# Java Swing - How to disable a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have several `JComponent`s on a `JPanel` and I want to disable all of those components when I press a Start button.

At present, I am disabling all of the components explicitly by

```
component1.setEnabled(false);
:
:
```

But Is there anyway by which I can disable all of the components at once? I tried to disable the `JPanel` to which these components are added by

```
panel.setEnabled(false);
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Why would anyone do this?  Seems easier to put the Swing components on a JDialog that you make invisible when the user clicks the Ok button (which can be renamed Start).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I can speak for myself - I came here searching a way to disable particular area temporarily - to indicate it waits for some process to finish.
@YatendraGoel is there a reason for those `:` in your code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The panel should have a [`getComponents()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) method which can use in a loop to disable the sub-components without explicitly naming them.

Comment: +1 I've used this.  Warning though, if your sub-components are containers (e.g. boxes used for layout management) then you need to do it recursively.  Also, If you have components that get disabled for other reasons then re-enabling will defeat them.

Comment: Agree with staticman, it is a dangerous behaviour and you need care when using it because you will re-enable everything if you don't take some cautions. Perhaps it is a not a problem for your case then you can like this. Or if it is a pb, then you will probably have to memorize the states of the components before de-enabling them in order to reset them in the good state.

Comment: Its a bit tricky, but I wouldn't say dangerous. My normal approach would be to subclass `JPanel` and overwrite the `setEnabled()` method. There I would manually enable/disable the appropriate subcomponents, based on the internal state.

Comment: @staticman @MatthieuBROUILLARD I don't get it. why would calling `setEnabled(false)` re-enable anything?

Comment: @line He meant `setEnabled(true)` which would enable everything, even if you want to have readonly elements.

Answer (score 3):

The [Disabled Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/disabled-panel/) provides support for two approaches. One to recursively disable components, the other to "paint" the panel with a disabled look.

Answer (score 3):

The following method uses recursion to achieve this. Pass in any `Container`, and this method will return a `Component` array of all of the non-Container components located anywhere "inside" of the `Container`.

```
    private Component[] getComponents(Component container) {
        ArrayList<Component> list = null;

        try {
            list = new ArrayList<Component>(Arrays.asList(
                  ((Container) container).getComponents()));
            for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
                for (Component currentComponent : getComponents(list.get(index))) {
                    list.add(currentComponent);
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            list = new ArrayList<Component>();
        }

        return list.toArray(new Component[list.size()]);
        }
    }
```

Simply loop through the elements of the returned array and disable the components.

```
for(Component component : getComponents(container)) {
    component.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the **JXLayer**, with [LockableUI](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2008/07/jxlayer_30_lock.html).

Comment: downvoting because there is no explanation or example how to use it, and the link is now broken

Answer (score 0):

The following method should be all what you need to add, you can call it with `setEnableRec(panel, true)` or `setEnableRec(panel, false)`:

```
private void setEnableRec(Component container, boolean enable){
    container.setEnabled(enable);

    try {
        Component[] components= ((Container) container).getComponents();
        for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
            setEnableRec(components[i], enable);
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: if you move the first instruction `container.setEnabled(enable)` inside the catch, then you could keep certain functionality of the containers, e.g. `JTabbed` could still be clickeable.

Comment: also be careful because if one element should have kept disabled in the enabling loop, then this method would override everything.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling should occur recursively:

```
Queue<Component> queue = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(container.getComponents()));
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Component head = queue.poll();
    head.setEnabled(enable);
    if(head instanceof Container) {
        Container headCast = (Container) head;
        queue.addAll(Arrays.asList(headCast.getComponents()));
    }
}
```